# Динамически придать имя переменной из параметра класса

Tags: javascript

```
class AbstractClass {
  constructor(variableName) {
    this.variableName = variableName;
  }
```

На вход я получу строку - название переменной. Могу ли я потом динамически использовать variableName для создания новой переменной как ее имя?
Что-то вроде:

```
var this.variableName (в variableName пришло, например, "variable") = "значение", что в итоге стало бы равноценно: var variable = "значение".
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте скобочки:

`this[this.variableName] = значение`

Так можно создать любую переменную в объекте с неизвестным заранее именем.

Если вы хотите создать глобальную переменную, то воспользуйтесь

`window[this.variableName] = значение`.

Локальную переменную так создать нельзя.

И да, чтобы удалить такую переменную с объекта, используйте:

`delete obj[variableName]` - по сути равносильно `obj[variableName] = undefined`, но не уверен, что второй способ оптимален по затратам оперативной памяти (точнее, не уверен, что она будет очищена)